# Selenium, нажать на всплывающее окно в chrome

Tags: python, selenium

Как я могу нажать на эту кнопку, используя python и selenium?

[image]

Comment: Пока код сами не написали, то только в ручную.

Comment: Очень смешно. А можно пожалуйста пример кода? Нигде не нашёл, как можно взаимодействовать с подобными диалогами, видел только, что селениум умеет работать с алертами.

Comment: Посмотрите Настройка параметров Selenium WebDriver Класс Options включение и отключение расширений браузера.

Comment: Мне не нужно включить или отключить расширение, мне нужно его удалить, а затем поставить заново, либо каким-то другим образом стереть его данные

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946938/how-to-add-or-remove-chrome-extensions-after-selenium-web-driver-has-been-inst